# Epochs and other hyperparameters in Deep Q-Networks

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn

I was wondering about hyperparameters used in Deep Q-Networks. Considering the use of replay memory and target network, together with the epsilon-greedy policy, are the number of epochs different of 1 useful? In the affirmative case, which are the situations and benefits?

The reason is that we want to explore the environment, thus providing a high number of different samples, but at the same time, my intuition says that it can be useful for fast convergence of the Q-values.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "are the number of epochs different of 1 useful?"

Comment: It's simply the fact that epochs are > 1.